# Convergence of Fourier series in $L^\infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

So if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and $S_Nf\rightarrow f$ in $L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$ ($S_Nf$ is the partial sum of the fourier series of $f$), then $f$ is continuous. How do we show that this is true? In general, $S_Nf$ does not converge to $f$ in $L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$ for continuous $f$ correct? ($\mathbb{T}$ denote the one dimensional torus $[0,1)$.)

Many thanks

Comment: uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous

Comment: Yes that is true but then what is the significance of $L^\infty$ in this problem

Comment: $L^{\infty}$ convergence will imply uniform convergence.

Comment: Thanks, I have been forgeting basic measure theory materials

Comment: [Fej\'er Example may be helpful](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.caltech.edu%2Fcourses%2F09ma108bFourierSeriesNotes.pdf&ei=OowjVKGCMZWNuAS304GQDQ&usg=AFQjCNFFGUniJ2SWTNO-CD7wWTirQ9tbdQ&sig2=2ehtQvN7xFZxruEo1VbIPg&bvm=bv.76247554,d.c2E)